# How to update comboBox items when the database is being changed?

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite, qt, debugging

I fill the comboBox with items from database. When I try to add new item, erasing all items and adding them again, if db is being changed, I see these errors:

```
QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name 'qt_sql_default_connection', old connection removed.
QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name 'qt_sql_default_connection', old connection removed.
QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record created
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument' what(): stoi
21:41:04: Debugging of C:\Users\79107\Downloads\build-food_calculator-Desktop_Qt_6_2_2_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\debug\food_calculator.exe has finished with exit code 3.
```

```cpp
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    MainWindow::foodListConstructor();//function, that fills the comboBox
}

void MainWindow::foodListConstructor()
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("food_list.db");
    db.open();
    QSqlQuery query("SELECT food_name FROM food", db);
    if(query.isActive())
    {
        while(query.next())
        {
            ui->comboBox->addItem(query.value(0).toString());
        }
    }
}


void MainWindow::on_action_3_triggered()
{
    AddFood af(this);// in this new window a user writes what he wants to add
    af.setModal(true);
    af.exec();
    this->ui->comboBox->clear();
    this->ui->comboBox->addItem("test");
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("food_list.db");
    db.open();
    QSqlQuery query1("SELECT food_name FROM food", db);
    if(query1.isActive())
    {
        while(query1.next())
        {
            ui->comboBox->addItem(query1.value(0).toString());
        }
}
```

How to make it work and not to dupliacte items (this happens if I remove "this->ui->comboBox->clear();")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `foodListConstructor()` multiple times, you are going to be calling `addDatabase()` multiple times.  Which is perfectly fine, per the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#addDatabase):

> Adds a database to the list of database connections using the driver type and the connection name connectionName. **If there already exists a database connection called connectionName, that connection is removed.**

So it would seem you are simply seeing debug messages being output internally by Qt.  This is not a real error, so just ignore it.  Although, there is no point in adding the same database over and over.  I would suggest just adding it once, and then use [`QSqlDatabase::database()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#database) to access it when needed.

The `QSqlQuery` error is pretty self-explanatory.  You tried to read a field value when the query was not on an active record. Again, that appears like another internal debug message, not a real error.  Per the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#value):

> An invalid `QVariant` is returned if field index does not exist, if the query is inactive, or **if the query is positioned on an invalid record**.

Why are you getting an invalid `QVariant` from an inactive SQL record? That I couldn't say. You will have to figure that out for yourself.

But it explains the final `terminate` message, which is a real error.  You are calling [`toString()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#toString) on an *invalid* `QVariant`:

> Calling QVariant::toString() on an unsupported variant returns an empty string.

Somewhere along the way, `std::stoi()` is being called with a string that doesn't represent an integer value (ie, likely the empty string you are adding to the `comboBox`), so it throws a `std::invalid_argument` exception that you are not catching, which is escaping out of your app's main function, causing the C++ runtime to call `std::terminate()` to exit the app.

Where is `std::stoi()` being called?  You need to search your code for that.  Do you have some event handler hooked up to the `comboBox`?

With that said, try something more like this:

```cpp
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("food_list.db");
    foodListConstructor();
}

void MainWindow::foodListConstructor()
{
    ui->comboBox->clear();

    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::database("QSQLITE");
    QSqlQuery query("SELECT food_name FROM food", db);
    while (query.next())
    {
         QVariant v = query.value(0);
         if (v.isValid())
             ui->comboBox->addItem(v.toString());
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_action_3_triggered()
{
    AddFood af(this);
    af.setModal(true);
    af.exec();
    foodListConstructor();
}
```